# Limitar el numero de registros oracle

Tags: oracle

Uso oracle 11, tengo la sgte consulta:

```
select * from(select "Loss","Date" from TEST order by "Loss" desc) where rownum < 20
```

Esto me devuelve 20 registros que tengas el mayor "Loss", hay otra forma de hacerlo?

Mi duda es en la sgte consulta:

```
select * from(
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM "Date") AS years, Count("Loss") AS events, Max("Loss") 
AS max_losses, Sum("Loss") AS sum_losses 
FROM Test GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM "Date") 
ORDER BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM "Date")
) where rownum < 20
```

me tendria que dar algo asi:

```
2017 5  3210 500581.25 
2016 15 8900 1658226.32
```

Pero me esta dando

```
2017 233 3210 500581.25 
2016 675 8900 1658226.32
```

¿Cómo puedo obtener los 20 registros que tengan la mayor perdida en esa consulta?

Comment: probaste usando `limit`?

Comment: no se donde eactamente poner el limit, me da este error SQL command not properly ended, creo q es solo para mysql

Comment: Creo recordar que LIMIT solo funciona en las ultimas versiones de Oracle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes que hacer una query de tu query limitando con rownum

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM "Date") AS years, Count("Loss") AS events, Max("Loss") 
    AS max_losses, Sum("Loss") AS sum_losses 
    FROM Test GROUP BY  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM "Date")
    ORDER BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM "Date") 
) WHERE ROWNUM <= 20
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60853/discussion-on-answer-by-lithorell-limitar-el-numero-de-registros-oracle).

Answer (score 0):

A partir de Oracle 12c R1 (12.1) existe una construcción para limitar el número de resultados, la [Row limiting clause](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/row-limiting-clause-for-top-n-queries-12cr1). Es un poco más compleja que el `LIMIT` de MySQL, pero funciona.

Para obtener los primeros 20 registros, la cláusula adecuada sería `FETCH FIRST 20 ROWS ONLY`, al final de la consulta.

Comment: uso oracle 11, he añadido lo que me dices pero obtengo este error : SQL command not properly ended

Comment: Esta solución sólo es válida a partir de la versión 12c R1, cuando implementaron esta nueva cláusula. Para hacerlo en versiones anteriores envuelve tu query con otra y limita los resultados con ROWNUM.

Comment: es lo q estoy intentado pero no me funciona, edite mi pregunta de la forma que mencionas que lo haga

Answer (score 0):

Esta consulta limita los resultados a los 20 registros con el valor más alto de "Loss":

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT "Loss","Date", ROWNUM rn
  FROM TEST 
  ORDER BY "Loss" DESC
)
WHERE rn <= 20;
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).